# How to increase idle time of "LaunchPad" for SQL Server external scripts?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, python

`sp_execute_external_script` can take a while to initialize when not run for a short time.  How do I set the idle time on the controller Launchpad process to keep it from shutting down too soon?

Note I am not talking about reusing the same Python session as I know each call uses its own session. What I am referring to is that when you execute `sp_execute_external_script` for a language it takes a while to start up. If you call `sp_execute_external_script` again in a short time then it runs immediately.  However, if you wait a while and execute it again it takes a while to execute as (I think) the Launchpad controller has reached an idle time and shutdown.  See [this article](https://nielsberglund.com/2018/05/20/sp_execute_external_script-and-sql-compute-context---i/) about SQL Server using the Launchpad process to created links to Python, R, and soon Java.

Is there a way to increase this idle time?

Comment: Would love to know this for running R scripts too - they have exactly the same issue here (about ~20 seconds to launch Launchpad when idle, 0 seconds afterwards) - but I've never been able to get anywhere with the problem sadly

Comment: I dont think there is a way to increase the idle time. A dirty trick will be to use `sp_execute_external_script` call a dummy `select 1 from Table` possibly scheduled using sql agent job or some windows task scheduler every x seconds.